# How to pass component to onClick in react

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native, jsx

```
import React from 'react'

export default () => {
  function clickHandler() {
    console.log('Button clicked')
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={clickHandler}>Click</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

In the above code we see that a function has been passed to the onClick.In the same way to the onClick I need to pass a diffrent component which is present in the same src. This component consists of a .js and a .css file.Could you please help me out with it. Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you want to pass a component? What is the expected result?

Comment: Could you elaborate, why would you want to pass a component to an onClick function?

Comment: This sound wrong. I kindly suggest to use a different approach.

Comment: What you want is  [Conditional Rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#gatsby-focus-wrapper) this example should help you https://codepen.io/gaearon/pen/QKzAgB

Comment: Do you want to show / hide a component on click of sometthing?

Comment: @MikaelsSlava there is a main page which consists of a button on click of that button this should be displayed

Comment: @AjeetShah yes ..I want this page to be displayed on click of a button

Comment: @arnelisk I have elaborated in the previous comment please check it out

Comment: You can use conditional rendering: `{ condition && <MyComponent /> }`. You don't need to pass anything (or component). If you can't do that, you should explain more on what you are trying to achieve. Feel free to edit your question.

Comment: @AjeetShah Thank you it helped

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using classes instead of functions, your **other** component should look like this:

```
import React from 'react'

class ShowThisAfterClick extends React.Component {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>This is what you want to show</p>
    </div>
  )
}
export default ShowThisAfterClick
```

And now you should update the component you've shown:

```
import React from 'react'
import ShowThisAfterClick from './where/you/put/the/ShowThisAfterClick.js'

class Main extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = { isButtonClicked: false }

    this.clickHandler = this.clickhandler.bind(this)
  }
  
  clickHandler() {
    this.setState({ isButtonClicked: true })
  }
  
  render() {
    const { isButtonClicked } = this.state
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={ this.clickHandler }>Click</button>
        { isButtonClicked ? <ShowThisAfterClick /> : ''}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
export default Main
```

If you want to keep using functions, then I would kindly suggest to [read the manual](https://reactjs.org/docs/), it is more than well written.